# Install resty.http with already installed openresty

Tags: nginx, lua, google-oauth, openresty

I installed openresty-1.13.6.1 but it lacks 'resty.http' module. My openresty is installed in /usr/local/openresty and i need to integrate resty.http module with it. How to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just copy both files (https://github.com/pintsized/lua-resty-http/tree/master/lib/resty) into /usr/local/openresty/lualib folder.

Update:

Resulted file structure should be:

```
/usr/local/openresty/lualib/resty/http.lua
/usr/local/openresty/lualib/resty/http_headers.lua
```

Comment: Did not work for me. Added the files and I got a different error message than before: ERROR: .../local/Cellar/openresty/1.21.4.2_1/lualib/resty/http.lua:166: module 'resty.http_connect' not found

Comment: Things are changed ;-) Now I see new file within the lib - https://github.com/ledgetech/lua-resty-http/blob/master/lib/resty/http_connect.lua - you should copy it as well